# JAVA getConstructor throws NoSuchMethodException

Tags: java, reflection

I'm new in JAVA 
and I'm trying to learn [reflection](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/index.html).
I want to get specific constructor (picking the example form [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/constructors.html)) 
from my class :

```
public class Example1 {
    public Example1() {
    }

    public Example1(int i) {
    }

    public Example1(String s) {
        System.out.println("using param = " + s);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {  
        Class<?>[] paramTypes = String.class.getClasses();
        Constructor<Example1> ctor = Example1.class.getConstructor(paramTypes);
        ctor.newInstance("test");
    }
}
```

I get `NoSuchMethodException` when trying to instantiate `ctor`

What am I missing here?

Comment: Your code doesn't actually throw any exception. It also doesn't compile as you don't check for exceptions NoSuchMethodException and SecurityException in main().

Comment: @TomášZíma I cant say what it is not compiling in my station 
,
by the way why the "-1" ?

Comment: it's not compiling because of the reason I told you -- there are exceptions for which you need to check. Example in answer I posted should be working on your station, isn't it? BTW, I didn't downvote your question...

Comment: Please add `throws Exception` to your `main()` method and add attempt to actually instantiate the class (`ctor.newInstance("foo")`). Question will then meet the site's criteria and I'll upvote it (as it is, it actually doesn't compile/run).

Comment: @LordTitiKaka I suspect that `-1` may have something to do  with your code example, since because it doesn't compile it prevents us from reproducing your problem. This means that (1) answering your question is harder (2) future readers may not be able to determine if they are facing same problem as you. Try to improving your example for instance by adding `throws Exception` in your `main` method (like @TomášZíma suggested).

Comment: I attempted to edit the question, but it have to be peer-reviewed. It will take some time until the changes are visible (if it'd be accepted).

Comment: @TomášZíma If I remember correctly it can be instantly accepted by author of post. EDIT: It seems that my memory was right :)

Comment: While edited code now compiles fine it throws `IllegalArgumentException`, not `NoSuchMethodException` as you claim in title and in your post (so it is still not very useful for potentially readers searching for solution for `NoSuchMethodException`)

Comment: @TomášZíma Done
for the record I dont really care about the score but I still think my question is well written for one with small amount of exp. at hand

Comment: @LordTitiKaka It's for people who will find this question later.

Comment: One more last edit :) Now it throws NoSuchMethodException, just like he mentions. Since `String.class.getClasses()` returns empty array AND there actually was non-parametric constructor, it found it. The problem occurred while trying to instantiate it (`IllegalArgumentException`). I think it should be OK and helpful for others now.

Comment: My edit got rejected (voting 3:2). I just removed the non-parametric constructor. Now the question is incorrect, doesn't make sense and should be removed, my answer was a waste of time and all the edits was a waste of time too, hence I'm quite starting to dislike this site.

Comment: @TomášZíma In [original version of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/29195039/1) there was also public no-argument constructor so people could assume that you tried to change too much, IMO they did good job because it is OP job to provide example which would let us reproduce described problem, not editors (since they could easily miss important detail which may be causing problem).

Comment: @TomášZíma "*Now the question is incorrect*" no, it was incorrect from very beginning. If someone is looking for an answer and is posting code example it is his/her job to make sure that this example actually reproduces this problem (and doesn't introduce other ones). That is why I voted to put this question on-hold to prevent posting any answers until question will be corrected.

Comment: @TomášZíma Problem with Stack Overflow is that people (especially new here) forgot (or didn't know from start) that ["we're working together to build a library of **detailed** answers to every question about programming"](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). What this means? That we are not here to help only OP, but every reader which may face similar problem. That is why we expect from questions to be precise so we could create 100% accurate answer. In this case question should be put on hold. To avoid stressful situations try to answer only questions where you are able to reproduce OP problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Working example:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;

public class Test {
    public Test(String str) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }

    public Test(int a, int b) {
        System.out.println("Sum is " + (a + b));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Constructor<Test> constructorStr = Test.class.getConstructor(String.class);
        constructorStr.newInstance("Hello, world!");

        Constructor<Test> constructorInts = Test.class.getConstructor(int.class, int.class);
        constructorInts.newInstance(2, 3);
    }
}
```

Note that method `getConstructor` actually doesn't take an array. It's defined like:

```
public Constructor<T> getConstructor(Class<?>... parameterTypes) {
```

... meaning that it accepts variable amount of arguments which should have been passed as I did. Passing an array is possible too, but it's not necessary.

What you've done originally was equivalent to:

```
    Constructor<Test> constructor = Test.class.getConstructor(String.class.getClasses());
    constructor.newInstance("Hello");
```

But, what does `String.class.getClasses()` return? Good question! Lets go debug:

```
    Class<?>[] classes = String.class.getClasses();
    System.out.println(classes.length); // prints 0
```

There's a documentation about `getClasses()`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getClasses. Check it and you'll find out the reason why it's so.

For the sake of completeness. The super-original-question (before edits) contained one more constructor - a non-parametric one:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;

public class Example1 {
    public Example1() {
    }

    public Example1(String s) {
        System.out.println("using param = " + s);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {  
        Constructor<Example1> ctor = Example1.class.getConstructor(String.class.getClasses());
        ctor.newInstance("test");
    }
}
```

The problem which occurs here is `IllegalArgumentException` being thrown. It's because even though `String.class.getClasses()` returns an empty array, there actually is constructor which matches the criteria - a non-parametric constructor! It doesn't have any arguments and the array returned by `String.class.getClasses()` doesn't contain anything too. This means that constructor is successfully found, but when trying to instantiate it using `ctor.newInstance("test")`, it fails because the found constructor **doesn't** accept any arguments.

Comment: This was happening to me because I had removed "public" from    public    MainCameraRollXML(Context context)

Answer (score -1):

Try it using

```
Constructor<example1> ctor = examTesting.getConstructor(new Class[]{String.class});
```

This will return the constructor with one parameter of type String. Your method might return multiple values and therefore a constructor with multiple parameter is searched but not found -> NoSuchMethodException is thrown.

More information about getClasses(): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getClasses%28%29